# Is it possible to get raw events from Firebase analytics using api without BigQuery?

Tags: firebase-analytics

We need to extract raw events from Firebase Analytics using python SDK. Actually, we can link a BigQuery to a firebase and access raw events through BigQuery. But it is not clear from the documentation is there any other ways to extract events without BigQuery?